# MySQL Huge table select performance

Tags: mysql

I currently have a table with 10 million rows and need to increase the performance drastically.

I have thought about dividing this 1 table into 20 smaller tables of 500k but I could not get an increase in performance.

I have created 4 indexes for 4 columns and converted all the columns to INT's and I have another column that is a bit.

my basic query is `select primary from from mytable where column1 = int and bitcolumn = b'1'`, this still is very slow, is there anything I can do to increase the performance?

**Server Spec**

32GB Memory, 2TB storage, and using the standard ini file, also my processor is AMD Phenom II X6 1090T

Comment: @barsju LOL, the CPU doesn't even get above 10% when running the queries so i don't think that'll help

Comment: Are you always selecting on only one column + the bit?

Comment: Have you tried tweaking memory usage etc?

Comment: 10 million rows is not "huge".  Please define "slow" in your question and post your MySQL configuration (leave out passwords or other sensitive information).  There's an excellent chance that you're not dedicating memory properly to MySQL).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson most of the time yeah, however it do need to select x,x,x from mytable where column1 = int, column 2 = int, column 3 = int

Comment: @EricJ. how many 10mil row DB's you deal with.  And about 9 seconds per query slow

Comment: How many rows are you returning? Please provide more details, including schema.

Comment: I dealt with billions of rows.  Yes, 9 seconds is quite slow for a straight select on 10 million rows to *begin* returning results.  If you are measuring time to return say 99% of rows across a slow line, that's an entirely different matter.  More details needed.

Comment: @MarcusAdams anywhere from 90-1100

Comment: @EricJ. billion rows in one table?

Comment: Mike: Billions sharded across multiple DB servers.  But way more than 10m on a given server.

Comment: @EricJ. I'm just trying to understand if 10MIl is to much to get reliable performance or do I need to split it maybe into 4 tables

Comment: @Mike: Post your server specs (memory and disk storage) and your MySQL ini file (less any passwords). Let's see why your selects are slow before discussing sharding.  I would expect sub-second response given what I know so far from your question, so based on that, I would say no, you don't need to shard but rather address the underlying performance issue.

Comment: @EricJ. My server spec is as follow 32GB Memory, 2TB storage, and using the standard ini file, also my processor is AMD Phenom II X6 1090T

Comment: The "standard" ini file that ships with MySQL is HORRIBLY wrong for modern processing environments.  If you post it, I'll give you advice on how to change it.  Also, what are your disk subsystems?  RAID 0, RAID 1... and local disks, NAS, SAN, ...?

Comment: Please post the schema, at least the tables/columns in the query, and the actual query.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to giving the mysql server more memory to play with, remove unnecessary indexes and make sure you have index on column1 (in your case). Add a limit clause to the sql if possible.

Comment: It is generally good advice to remove unnecessary indices, but that will not affect SELECT performance.  It will affect INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE performance.

Comment: Get some tips here for tuning: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-parameters.html

Comment: @EricJ. Yes, but the wrong indices will take up memory and if the configuration is wrong they may be pushed to disk and slow down the system.

Comment: Pushing an unused index to disk will have zero effect on a SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to reliably diagnose the issue, but you state that you're using "the default" my.cnf / my.ini file on a system with 32G of memory.

From the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html#option-files-preconfigured) the following pre-configured files are shipped:

- Small: System has <64MB memory, and MySQL is not used often.
- Medium: System has at least 64MB memory
- Large: System has at least 512MB memory and the server will run mainly MySQL.
- Huge: System has at least 1GB memory and the server will run mainly MySQL.
- Heavy: System has at least 4GB memory and the server will run mainly MySQL.

Best case, you're using a configuration file that utilizes 1/8th of the memory on your system (if you are using the "Heavy" file, which as far as I recall is not the default one.  I think the default one is Medium or perhaps Large).

I suggest editing your my.cnf file appropriately.

There [several areas of MySQL](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/29/what-to-tune-in-mysql-server-after-installation/) for which the memory allocation can be tweaked to maximize performance for your particular case.  You can post your my.cnf / my.ini file here for more specific advice.  You can also use [MySQL Tuner](https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl) to get some automated advice.

Answer (score 0):

Download this (on your server):

[MySQLTuner.pl](http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl)

Install it, run it and see what it says - even better paste the output here.

Answer (score 0):

I made something that make a big difference in the query time
but it is may not useful for all cases, just in my case

I have a huge table (about 2,350,000 records), but I can expect the exact place that I should play with

so I added this condition `WHERE id > '2300000'` as I said this is my case, but it may help others
so the full query will be:

```
SELECT primary from mytable where id > '2300000' AND column1 = int AND bitcolumn = b'1'
```

The query time was 2~3 seconds and not it is less than 0.01

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your query

```
select primary from from mytable where column1 = int and bitcolumn = b'1'
```

has some errors, like two `from` clauses. Second thing, splitting the table and using an unnecessary index never helps in performance. Some tips to follow are:

> 1) Use a composite index if you repeatedly query some columns together. But precautions must be taken, because in a composite index the order of placing a column in the index matters a lot.
>
> 2) The primary key is more helpful if it's on `int` column.
>
> 3) Read some articles on indices and optimization, they are so many, search on Google.